# Importing 2nd Sheet of Excel doc in Stata, Without Knowing its Name

Tags: for-loop, stata

I'm appending a series of excel sheets together. For each excel doc, I want the 2nd sheet. However, the name of the 2nd sheet varies unpredictably.

How do I tell Stata to import the 2nd sheet without referencing its name?

```
import excel "test1.xlsx", sheet("xxxx") firstrow clear
save "append.dta", replace

forvalues i = 2/100{
   import excel "test`i'.xlsx", sheet("yyyy") firstrow clear
   append using "append.dta"
   save "append.dta", replace
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the describe option of import excel.

```
import excel using "test.xlsx", describe
import excel using "test.xlsx", sheet("`r(worksheet_2)'") firstrow clear
```

Answer (score 1):

The Stata help for import excel includes the describe option, and at the bottom of the help file, a discussion of how the describe option stores worksheet names in r().